# Kofax project and batch class

Tags: kofax

Kofax Capture Version 9
I have an existing Project and Batch class that works, built previously by Kofax engineer.

What I need to do is change the script in the project to use a new DB connection. This seemed simple enough.

Using project builder I copied the existing project, altered the script and saved the project. Using Capture Administration I copied the existing batch class and then used Synchronize Kofax Transformation Project and pointed to the new project. All this seemed to work without error.

However the script being executed is the original not my altered one, any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure you are creating a new batch after publishing your change.  The batch class class update function works in very limited scenarios, so I don't generally recommend it.
- There are many ways that a database connection might be handled in script.  Usually I would expect that a function at the project script level handles the connection and is called from any sub class, but you might want to check any sub classes to make sure they aren't using locally defined connection strings.
- Even if you are making a connection in script (which you've now changed), you might also be using product features that use databases.  Open Project Settings and check the Databases tab.

  - If there are relational databases listed, simply change as needed.
  - If you are actually using "Remote Fuzzy" databases then these might be using Kofax Search and Matching Server which connects to a relational database to build the fuzzy db.  In this case you would need to use KSMS Admin to change the connection on the KSMS server.
  - If you are using "Local Fuzzy" databases then the info is based on the content of a text file.  You might have some external process (possibly Markview) that dumps this text file from a database.

Comment: The DB connection is made in script and uses an ODBC connection to Oracle. The result set is displayed in a Dialog, all of which I can see in the project parent class and inherited by it's children. There are no database connections and any fuzzy DB use is limited to static items that act as a list. Changes just do not seem to be adopted by the new batch class, be it copied or created. The only way I see how to link a batch class to a project is thru Synchronize.

Comment: Create a test batch class with your updated project.  Do you see your changes now?  If not, add a msgbox or some other super obvious change to confirm whether you are having a problem specific to your db connection or a problem loading the correct updated project.

Comment: I had tried that without success. However I have found the process works on the test server not the production server. I can only assume that the batch classes are being test exported and production imported.
More to follow as I progress, appreciate your input.

Comment: OK, I exported the batch class from test to prod box, all working well, seems the engineer used this approach and then cleaned up, leaving no evidence of such.
I do have a question, lets assume I have some scans that took place prior to my update, it seems they will validate with the previous code, not the new, anyway of forcing un validated batches to use the new class? It has the same name.

Comment: They retain the version they were created with.  In Batch Manager you can right click and update the batch class to the latest version.  However this can only handle limited scenarios and if it detects a change it cannot handle then it will not be able to update.  If you removed the batch class and imported a new one fo the same name I doubt it will see it as an update, and instead just a new batch class altogether.